# angular star rating from: npm i angular-star-rating

Tags: angular

I am downloading angular star rating package from this website
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-star-rating

I have included StarRatingModule.forRoot() in the imports under app.module.

However, when i follow the guide and put the following tag in my application, it complained that "compiler.es5.js:1694
Can't bind to 'rating' since it isn't a known property of 'star-rating-comp'."

```
<star-rating-comp [starType]="'svg'" [rating]="2.63"></star-rating-comp>
```

Can someone please assist? Thx

Comment: are you using it in a submodule of your application maybe? if so, you will have to import StartRatingModule there as well

Answer (score 3):

Selector **star-rating-comp** seem to be out of date. I use **star-rating** and it works.